# Problem with printing inside the loop: for

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, collections

I have problem reading/println after the first two FOR loop in this method. 
This is strange. How can I solve this problem?

```
private int spacing() {
    int n = numberOfTriangles();

    ArrayList<Double> list_Xs1 = new ArrayList<Double>(); 
    ArrayList<Double> list_Ys1 = new ArrayList<Double>(); 

    for(Polygon p:triangles){
        double cX = p.xpoints[0];
        double cY = p.ypoints[2];
        list_Ys1.add(cY);
        list_Xs1.add(cX);
    }

    //Remove duplicate key in X 
    HashSet<Double> hashSet_list_Xs1= new HashSet<Double>(list_Xs1);
    ArrayList<Double> list_Xs2  = new ArrayList<Double>(hashSet_list_Xs1);
    Collections.sort(list_Xs2);

    //Remove duplicate key in Y 
    HashSet<Double> hashSet_list_Ys1= new HashSet<Double>(list_Ys1);
    ArrayList<Double> list_Ys2  = new ArrayList<Double>(hashSet_list_Ys1);
    Collections.sort(list_Ys2);

    ArrayList<Double> list_Xs3 = new ArrayList<Double>(); 
    ArrayList<Double> list_Ys3 = new ArrayList<Double>(); 
    double distanceX = 0.0,distanceY=0.0;

    //Get Distance between X coordinate
    for (int j=0; j<list_Xs2.size(); j++){
        distanceX = Math.abs(list_Xs2.get(j) - list_Xs2.get(j+1));
        list_Xs3.add(distanceX);
        System.out.println("I am able to print everything inside this loop");
    }

    System.out.println("After the LOOP for (int j=0; j<list_Xs2.size(); j++), the method seems stop reading the remaining line e.g. cannot print after this loop ");

    //Get Distance between Y coordinate     
    for (int i=0; i<list_Ys2.size(); i++){
        distanceY = Math.abs(list_Ys2.get(i) - list_Ys2.get(i+1));
        list_Ys3.add(distanceY);
        System.out.println("Nothing printed in this loop");
    }

    //Remove duplicate key in Y 
    HashSet<Double> hashSet_list_Ys2= new HashSet<Double>(list_Ys3);
    ArrayList<Double> list_Ys4      = new ArrayList<Double>(hashSet_list_Ys2) ;

    //Remove duplicate key in X 
    HashSet<Double> hashSet_list_Xs2 = new HashSet<Double>(list_Xs3);
    ArrayList<Double> list_Xs4    = new ArrayList<Double>(hashSet_list_Xs2) ;

    int distinctDistance_Xs = list_Xs4.size(); 
    int distinctDistance_Ys = list_Ys4.size(); 


    int nSpacing = distinctDistance_Xs + distinctDistance_Ys;

    int RMspacing=0;
    if (n==1)
        RMspacing = 1;
    else if (n != 1)
        RMspacing = 1 - ((nSpacing-1)/(2*(n-1)));

    return RMspacing;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't your environment include a debugger?  What do you use for development?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for all the suggestions, I forgot about the last iteration which number is the same with the last iteration. I solved the problem by adding -1.

```
 for (int j=0; j<list_Xs2.size()-1; j++){
    ....
 }


 for (int j=0; j<list_Ys2.size()-1; j++){
    ....
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Any exceptions thrown?

If not, print out the value of list_Ys2.size(), in all probability it's zero.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int j=0; j<list_Xs2.size(); j++){
  distanceX = Math.abs(list_Xs2.get(j) - list_Xs2.get(j+1));
  ...
}
```

This should throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException for the last iteration, when `j+1` equals `size()`

Answer (score 1):

Your code runs into an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` in the `list_Xs2` loop; apparently your execution environment ignores stderr, which is a bad idea. Additionally, I'd suggest taking the time to learn using a debugger, which makes investigating this kind of problem very quick and easy.